External call recipient can consume all transaction gas
External call recipients consume all transaction gas, leading to transaction reversion.
How to Prevent this?

When making external calls in Solidity, the default behavior is to forward all available gas to the recipient contract, This means that the recipient contract can consume the entire gas limit of the transaction, resulting in the transaction being reverted.
Example:
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Caller {
    function callExternal(address _recipient) external {
        // Make an external call to the recipient contract
        (bool success, ) = _recipient.call("");
        require(success, "External call failed");
    }
}

In this code, if a contract function of the recipient contract consumes a large amount of gas, it can cause the transaction to revert. This can lead to unexpected results and potential vulnerabilities.
To prevent this, specify the gas amount:
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Caller {
    function callExternal(address _recipient) external {
        // External call with gas limit
        (bool success, ) = _recipient.call{gas: 100000}("");
        require(success, "External call failed");
    }
}

Always specify a gas limit when making external calls using addr.call{gas: <amount>}() syntax. or consider using the ExcessivelySafeCall library that provides added safety measures.
